# Create a new dataframe where desired values are spread across multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

Given the following dataframe df:

```
Symbol   X       X.1     X.2       X.3         X.4        X.5        X.6  X.7  X.8  X.9 X.10 X.11 X.12 X.13 X.14 X.15 X.16
1 LOC6540581 Adh    Adh-PA GG25120 Dere\\Adh  GG25120-PA       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 LOC6541346 eve    CG2328  eve-PA   GG24126   Dere\\eve  CG2328-PA GG24126-PA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 LOC6548272 amy     Amy-p GG22216  Amy-p-PA Dere\\Amy-p GG22216-PA       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

I need to create a new data frame that is composed by the Symbol column (df$Symbol) and one additional column whose values are only the one starting with GG from the dataframe df.

I have no idea how to proceed. Any ideas? Both [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) answers are welcome !

I was considering to subset the dataframe in R where I would have a new dataframe with two columns one with the Symbol column and the other with just the values that start with *GG* from the other columns.

Desired output:

```
Symbol     X
LOC6540581 GG25120
LOC6541346 GG24126
LOC6548272 GG22216
```

Comment: In the first row `GG25120` and `GG25120-PA` are starting with `GG`. Which should be taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace all the values that are not starting with `GG` with `NA`, then `unite` the columns, `separate` to just 2 columns to only get the first non-NA values in column `X`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(-Symbol, ~gsub("^[^GG].*",NA, .x))) %>% 
  unite(SX, everything(), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  separate(SX, into = c("Symbol", "X"))

#>       Symbol       X
#> 1 LOC6540581 GG25120
#> 2 LOC6541346 GG24126
#> 3 LOC6548272 GG22216
```

#### Data:

```
read.table(text = "Symbol   X       X.1     X.2       X.3         X.4        X.5        X.6  X.7  X.8  X.9 X.10 X.11 X.12 X.13 X.14 X.15 X.16
1 LOC6540581 Adh    Adh-PA GG25120 Dere\\Adh  GG25120-PA       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 LOC6541346 eve    CG2328  eve-PA   GG24126   Dere\\eve  CG2328-PA GG24126-PA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 LOC6548272 amy     Amy-p GG22216  Amy-p-PA Dere\\Amy-p GG22216-PA       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>", 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "<NA>", header= TRUE) -> df1
```

Comment: I've never thought about using `unite()` with `na.rm = TRUE` like this - nice!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two R solutions, the first using the [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) package and the second using [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/). Both approaches are based [SQL coalesce](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp). They replace any strings that do not start with `"GG"` with `NA`, then take the first non-NA value, starting from the left, in each row.

The `data.table` method uses [`fcoaelsce()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.13.4/topics/fcoalesce):

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

# Select all columns except symbols
cols  <- names(dat)[names(dat)!="Symbol"]

dat[, 
    (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(grepl("^GG", x), x, NA_character_)),
    .SDcols = cols
][, X:= fcoalesce(.SD), .SDcols = cols
][, .(Symbol, X)]

#        Symbol       X
# 1: LOC6540581 GG25120
# 2: LOC6541346 GG24126
# 3: LOC6548272 GG22216
```

Alternatively here is a `dplyr` approach in R to do the same:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    mutate(
        across(!Symbol, \(x) fifelse(grepl("^GG", x), x, NA_character_))
    ) %>%
    transmute(
        Symbol,
        X = coalesce(!!!select(., starts_with("X")))
    )

#       Symbol       X
# 1 LOC6540581 GG25120
# 2 LOC6541346 GG24126
# 3 LOC6548272 GG22216
```

This uses the [`dplyr::coalesce`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) function.

`data.table` is often faster than `dplyr`, although note that the approach above will modify your original data in place. The `dplyr` method makes a copy of the data.

#### Data

```r
structure(list(Symbol = c("LOC6540581", "LOC6541346", "LOC6548272"
), X = c("Adh", "eve", "amy"), X.1 = c("Adh-PA", "CG2328", "Amy-p"
), X.2 = c("GG25120", "eve-PA", "GG22216"), X.3 = c("Dere\\Adh",
"GG24126", "Amy-p-PA"), X.4 = c("GG25120-PA", "Dere\\eve", "Dere\\Amy-p"
), X.5 = c(NA, "CG2328-PA", "GG22216-PA"), X.6 = c(NA, "GG24126-PA",
NA), X.7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), X.8 = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_), X.9 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_), X.10 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), X.11 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), X.12 = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_), X.13 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_), X.14 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), X.15 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), X.16 = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Nice use of tidyeval in `coalesce`. +1

Answer (score 0):

A *base* way using `apply` and `grep` taking those starting with `GG` and having then only numbers.

```
cbind(DF[1], X = apply(DF[-1], 1, grep, pattern = "^GG\\d+$", value = TRUE))
#      Symbol       X
#1 LOC6540581 GG25120
#2 LOC6541346 GG24126
#3 LOC6548272 GG22216
```

Or using `startsWith` and taking the first match.

```
cbind(DF[1], X = apply(DF[-1], 1, \(x) x[startsWith(x, "GG")][1]))
#      Symbol       X
#1 LOC6540581 GG25120
#2 LOC6541346 GG24126
#3 LOC6548272 GG22216
```

Data

```
DF <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Symbol   X       X.1     X.2       X.3         X.4        X.5        X.6  X.7  X.8  X.9 X.10 X.11 X.12 X.13 X.14 X.15 X.16
1 LOC6540581 Adh    Adh-PA GG25120 Dere\\Adh  GG25120-PA       <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 LOC6541346 eve    CG2328  eve-PA   GG24126   Dere\\eve  CG2328-PA GG24126-PA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 LOC6548272 amy     Amy-p GG22216  Amy-p-PA Dere\\Amy-p GG22216-PA       <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `tidyverse` option could be:

```
df %>%
 transmute(Symbol,
           X = pmap_chr(across(-Symbol), ~ c(...)[str_which(c(...), "^GG")][1]))

      Symbol       X
1 LOC6540581 GG25120
2 LOC6541346 GG24126
3 LOC6548272 GG22216
```